# Labeling values in a GNUplot heatmap

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to generate a heat map using gnu plot.

```
set title "Heat Map"

plot '-' matrix with image

10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 0
30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 0   0
40  50  60  70  80  90  100 0   0   0
50  60  70  80  90  100 0   0   0   0
60  70  80  90  100 0   0   0   0   0
70  80  90  100 0   0   0   0   0   0
80  90  100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
90  100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
e
```

[image: Image generated]

Along the axes I get values -2 0 2 4 6 8 10, and I would like to replace those with a custom string. I cannot find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
set border 0 # remove box around map
set xtics ("first" 0, "sec." 2, "last" 9) # set special strings on selected position on x axes
set ytics ("first" 0, "sec." 2, "last" 9) # set special strings on selected position on y axes
unset key # without key

set title "Heat Map"
plot '-' matrix with image

10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 0
30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100 0   0
40  50  60  70  80  90  100 0   0   0
50  60  70  80  90  100 0   0   0   0
60  70  80  90  100 0   0   0   0   0
70  80  90  100 0   0   0   0   0   0
80  90  100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
90  100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
100 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
e
```